# How to find the closed form of a relatively simple sum?

Tags: summation

I'm trying to find the sum $ \sum_{n=1,3,5}^\infty \frac{8}{n \sinh (n \pi)} $

```
Sum[8/(Sinh[n*Pi]*n), {n, 1, Infinity, 2}]
```

which I know is ln(2), but Mathematica only computes it as NSum[] and returns the numerical value of .693... Is there a way to find the closed form of this sum?

Comment: ``AssociationMap[Sum[8/(Sinh[n*Pi]*n), {n, 1, Infinity, 2}, Method -> #] &, Sum`SumMethodDump`$availableSumMethods]`` was unsuccessful. Ditto for summing with `(2n-1)` for `n`, from `1` to `Infinity`.

Comment: @MichaelE2  `Sum\`SumMethodDump\`$availableSumMethods` returns unevaluated for me.

Comment: @MichaelE2  I am using "11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" when I fail to reproduce your result.  `Information[Sum\`SumMethodDump\`$availableSumMethods]` seems to recognize the symbol, although it provides no information on it , only the symbol itself surrounded by a light blue background with a blue line above.  Any suggestions?  By the way, how did you know that this symbol would produce results?

Comment: @bbgodfrey You have to initialize/autoload the variable by evaluating a sum.  I used `Sum[1/n^2, {n, Infinity}, Method -> "Logarithmic"]` just now.  It was already loaded from trying the OP's sum, I guess.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Worked, thanks.  Where do you find this arcane information?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Guessed ``?Sum*`*Meth*``.  Occasionally you find option settings stored in a variable.